# Docker crash test with many containers of the same image

Tags: docker, containers, jupyterhub

I would like to make a docker crash test on my server, to see how many containers based on the same image my server will support. (Because I've installed  jupyterhub and I want to see how many containers can run in good condition.)

So how can I copy an existing container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to copy an existing container, just create new ones of the same image. For your purposes I would recommend using the  [scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) feature of docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
web:
  image: <someimage>
db:
  image: <someotherimage>
```

Then simply specify the amount of containers you would like to start:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose ps
$ docker-compose scale web=15 db=3
$ docker-compose ps
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it was just I need :)